# Navigate to nested screen react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I have a bottom tab navigator like so:

```
const Tab = BottomTabNavigator()

const BottomTab = () => (

  <Tab.Navigator>
    <Tab.Screen name = "Feed" component = {FeedNavigator}/>
    <Tab.Screen name = "Profile" component = {Profile}/>
  <Tab.Navigator>
)
```

The feed component is a Stack navigator like so:

```
const FeedNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator> 
      <Stack.Screen name = "Food" component = {Food}/>
      <Stack.Screen name = "MainFeed" component = {MainFeed}/>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}
```

how do i navigate from my Profile screen to the Food component inside the FeedNavigator and pass props to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

navigation.navigate('Feed', { screen: 'Food', params: { user: 'jane'},
});

Comment: the problem with this is that now everytime you try to access Feed from anywhere in the app it will automatically redirect you to Food

Answer (score 0):

**You can navigate in a nested navigator using below code.**

```
navigation.navigate('Feed',{ screen: 'Food',params : {}})
```